# Deploy same deployment several times with different values in Helm

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I have a situation in which I have an image which I need to deploy to an OpenShift cluster 3 instances, i.e. 3 containers of the same image.

Each container should run with a different configuration (e.g. port, env vars, etc.). Each of these containers should be accessible as a separate service.

This means that I need a separate Deployment resource for each of them.

I'm using Helm to do this, and currently I have this setup:

```
- Chart.yaml
- values1.yaml
- values2.yaml
- values3.yaml
- Values.yaml
- deployment.yaml
- configmap.yaml
- service.yaml
```

Currently what I do is, that I run `helm install` 3 times to achieve this:

```
$ helm install first_deployment -f values1.yaml 
$ helm install second_deployment -f values2.yaml 
$ helm install third_deployment -f values3.yaml
```

I want to be able to achieve the same goal with only 1 `helm install`

So basically what I would like is that helm will run `apply` to my deployment 3 times, each time with a different set of variables, i.e. different configuration.

My motivation for this is that I want all the deployments to appear in the same `Helm Release` in my OpenShift cluster.

Comment: I think you can't do it with the Helm alone. You'd some tool over Helm, like Ansible or some other Configuration Management toolkit.

Comment: You should be able to just make additional copies of the `deployment.yml` and `service.yml` files; Helm will install everything that's in the `templates` directory.